# Figure text in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm plotting quite simple with

```
plt.plot(a,b)
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

But I need a figure text. I know I can use `text(x, y, my_text)` but I don't always know which combinations of `x` and `y` are visible in the plot due to different plot values.

Can I instead place the text below the plot? I guess it's something like

```
fig = plt.figure()
fig.text(0,0,my_text)
fig.plot(a,b)
```

Comment: Yes, you can place the text below the plot.  Look around for "matplotlib caption".  Also, there' s very likely a way to get around "I don't always know.." if you explain the problem a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

(x, y) combination follow the next rules for figure coordinate system:

- (0, 0) is bottom left of the figure.
- (1, 1) is top right of the figure.

This is independent of the plot. You also can use axes coordinate and user data coordinate ([Transformations tutorial](http://matplotlib.org/users/transforms_tutorial.html#transforms-tutorial)).